# MYSQL select rows with all required cross reference values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A with Unique IDs and some values

```
A
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | X         | Y         | X         | ...       |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | dummyData | dummyData | dummyData | dummyData |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | dummyData | dummyData | dummyData | dummyData |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have table B containing IDs from A, and a tag value (varchar)

Each combination of the 2 fields is guaranteed to be unique

```
B
+----+-------+
| ID | Tag   |
+----+-------+
| 1  | TAG_A |
+----+-------+
| 1  | TAG_B |
+----+-------+
| 1  | TAG_C |
+----+-------+
| 2  | TAG_A |
+----+-------+
| 3  | TAG_B |
+----+-------+
```

I have a stored procedure that returns the tags I want for a given report

```
Exec SpGetTagsForReport
+-------+
| Tag   |
+-------+
| TAG_A |
+-------+
| TAG_B |
+-------+
```

What I need is to select all rows from table A where there is a table B entry for every tag in the stored procedure call.

In this scenario, I should get back only row 1 from table A

My first idea was to select select every table B row that matches the stored proc response

```
SELECT * INTO #reportTags FROM (Exec SpGetTagsForReport)

SELECT * INTO #matchingTags FROM B WHERE Tag IN (SELECT Tag FROM #reportTags )
```

then group and compare counts

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
         FROM #matchingTags 
         GROUP BY ID 
         HAVING COUNT(Tag) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reportTags)
        )
```

My question is, is this a worthwhile path to go down, or am I missing some really obvious SQL functionality that makes this trivial and/or only requires a single statement?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: this looks like SQL-server syntax.

Comment: it needs to work in mysql. SQL-server is pretty much all I know. which parts won't translate into mysql? Is it the temp table portion?

Comment: @Broom . . . The "#" in the table name and the `exec` look suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say you have a table `ReportTags` with *unique* tags needed for a report.

And you have a table `B` that has a mapping from `id` to `tag`.  You can get what you need using `group by` and `having`:

```
select b.id
from b join
     reporttags rt
     on b.tag = rt.tag
group by b.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) form reporttags);
```

Comment: basically just joined this to table A. works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: still working on reconfiguring to mysql, but it works in sql-server and this was the part I was confused about. I can reconfigure the temp table and proc call later when I implement it